# Norm inequality proof.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> I need to prove the following inequality:
>
> $$\|x\|_{p} \geqslant \|x\|_{q}$$ if $q \geqslant p$.

I tried to do it using this inequality:

$$\frac{d\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}|x|^{\alpha}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} }{d \alpha} \leqslant 0$$

After differentiation I got stuck in the following equation:

$$\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}|x_i|^{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right) \ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}|x_i|^{\alpha}\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}(|x_i|^{\alpha} \ln(|x_i|\right) \right)$$

Could someone help me to prove it, please?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously when $p=q$, $\|x\|_p=\|x\|_q$. Generally it should be 
$$
p<q\implies \|x\|_p<C\|x\|_q\tag 1
$$

By Holder's inequality
$$
\|x\|_p^p=\sum_{i=1}^d|x_i|^p\leqslant \left(\sum_{i=1}^d(|x_i|^p)^{\frac{q}{p}}\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^d1^{\frac{q}{q-p}}\right)^{\frac{q-p}{q}}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(|x_i|^q)\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}C^p=\|x\|_q^pC^p
$$
Where $C=d^{\frac{q-p}{pq}}$. So $(1)$ holds.